# draw a rectangle via a html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

im a beginner learner, i'm stuck at drawing a rectangle in a canvas in html 5;
my html code :

```
<script src="new 3y.js"></script>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="main">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400">
      test
    </canvas>
</section>
</body
```

my js code:

```
function doFirst() {
var x = document.getElementbyId('canvas');
canvas = x.getContext("2d");
canvas.strokeRect(10,10,100,200);
}

window.addEventListener("load" , doFirst ,false);
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the console? There's an error message waiting for you. A tip: JS is case-sensitive language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `document.getElementbyId`, but the `b` must be uppercase.

Fixing that, your code works fine:

```js
function doFirst() {
  var x = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas = x.getContext("2d");
  canvas.strokeRect(10,10,100,200);
}

window.addEventListener("load" , doFirst ,false);
```

```html
<body>
<section id="main">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400">
      test
    </canvas>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works now!!

Comment: @varunteja No problems, man! If my answer was useful for you, please upvote by clicking on the arrow! Thanks :)